# How to calculate $\inf_Y\sup_Xf(x,y)$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, linear-programming, supremum-and-infimum

Definitions first:
$X=[1,2]$
$Y=[-1,1]$ and $f(x,y):=x+xy$ and the question I asked myself would be to calculate this:
$\inf_Y\sup_Xf(x,y)$

As far as I have understood it you start by fixing $y$. What I would do is to have 3 cases:

1.)$y>0$

2.)$y=0$

3.)$y<0$

For the first case we would have $\inf_Y(2+2y)=0$

Second case: $\inf_Y2=2$

Now it is getting a bit more complicated if $y<0$ then the part $xy$ becomes smaller if $x$ is getting bigger or closer to $2$ So what do I now? Like thats the part Im having problems with, how do you take the sup now? How do you differentiate? I guess I am on the right track, maybe I am thinking too much and it is straightforward. I would love to see a good and long explanation going really int depth, such that I could use it for different examples, as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is correct to fix $y$ first. Since
$y\ge -1$ the function $g(x)=x(1+y)$ we take the sup of has nonnegative slope.
Therefore, that sup is $2(1+y)$. The inf of that is obviously zero.

Comment: It was unfortunately chosen. What if $Y=[-2,1]$

Comment: Hint: $$
\sup_{x\in[1,2]}x(1+y)=\left\{\begin{array}\,2(1+y)\,,&y\ge -1\,,\\ 1+y\,,&y\in[-2,-1)\,.\end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: So my approach was correct? You fix y take the sup and then inf.

Comment: This was correct simply because this is the ***meaning*** of $\inf_y\sup_x f(x,y)$. Like you do double sums and double integrals.